# Collect smart hard disk data

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, smart

How can I view SMART data on hardrives either on individual machines or (prefered) across an enterprise under windows 7/2008 r2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only [very limited WMI support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463395) for getting to SMART data.

Luckily, [smartctl](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartctl.8.html) from smartmontools which you probably know best from Linux distributions, exists as a [Windows port](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/Download#Windows-InstalltheWindowspackage). Running it either as a part of a machine startup script, through some kind of inventory solution or on demand via RPC (e.g. with [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb897553)) and capturing / saving the output should get you there.

Comment: if you need a gui for it for some reason, take a look at [gsmartctl](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/en/Home)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like SpeedFan to grab the data from individual machines.  I don't know of anything that can grab it globally though.